# js DOM divs manipulation problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am currently learning DOM, and found the following task quite hard to complete in an proper manner. The js code is supposed to:

1. append new divs, as a continuation of the existing ones,
2. remove the existing divs,
3. change colour of one div,
4. switch all div's text content.
   My issues:
   Task 1.  works but in a ugly way, new divs are appended in a continous manner, I would rather see them in vertical order, as the exisitng ones
   Task 4. works only for the first div. Rest stays as is.

```js
      function myFunctionAdd() {
        var node = document.createElement("outerDiv");
        var textnode = document.createTextNode("My Vertical Div#");
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        document.getElementById("add").appendChild(node);
      }
      function myFunctionRem() {
        document.getElementById("innerDiv1").outerHTML = "";
      }
      function myFunctionColour() {
        document.getElementsByTagName("z4")[0].setAttribute("class", "democlass");
      }
            function myFunctionChangeText() {
        var x = "a new txt";
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            document.getElementById("innerDiv1").innerHTML = x;
      }
}
```

```css
  .democlass {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tytul dokumentu</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <button onclick="myFunctionAdd()">New div</button>
      <button onclick="myFunctionRem()">Remove divs</button>
      <button onclick="myFunctionColour()">Colour change</button>
      <button onclick="myFunctionChangeText()">Div's new text</button>
    </header>
    <ul>
      <li id="">
                <div class="innerDiv1" myattr="">
                  <p> My Vertical Div1 </p>
                </div>
      </li>
      <li>
                <div class="innerDiv1" myattr="">
                    <p>My Vertical Div2 </p>
                </div>
      </li>
       <li>
                <div class="innerDiv1" myattr="4">
                    <z4>My Vertical Div3 </z4>
                </div>
       </li>
       <li id="add">
                <div class="innerDiv" myattr="">
                    <p>My Vertical Div4</p>
                </div>
       </li>
            
    </ul>
     
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are starting with inavlid html structure. `<div>` can not be direct child of `<ul>` and `<li>` must be child of `<ul>` and can't be child of `<div>`

Comment: Also you can't repeat element ID's , they are unique by definition. Use common class for repeating elements instead

Comment: thank you, I have made some modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version best comparing differences to see what had been changed.

Using div as a child of <ul> is invalid it must be <li>

Tags like <z4> aren't part of HTML standard and while you can make your own tags up they need to be properly registered and following strict naming convention to prevent conflicts of new HTML tags in future.

id of elements should be unique

```
  <html>
      <head>
        <title>Tytul dokumentu</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script>
          function myFunctionAdd() {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            
            li.appendChild(div);
            div.appendChild(p);
            
            p.textContent = "My Vertical Div#";
            
            document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
          }

          function myFunctionRem() {
            let list = document.getElementById("list");
            let deleteChild = list.firstElementChild;
            
            if (deleteChild) {
                list.removeChild(deleteChild);
             }
          }
          function myFunctionColour() {
           let list = document.getElementById("list");
            let items = list.children.length;
            
            for (var i = 0; i < items; i++){
                let li = list.children[i]
                li.className = "democlass";
            }
          }
          function myFunctionChangeText() {
            var x = "a new txt";
            
            let list = document.getElementById("list");
            let items = list.children.length;
            
            for (var i = 0; i < items; i++){
                let li = list.children[i]
                let div = li.firstElementChild;
                let p = div.firstElementChild;
                p.textContent = x;
            }
    }
        </script>
      </head>
      <style>
      .democlass {
      color: blue;
    }
      </style>
      <body>
        <header>
          <button onclick="myFunctionAdd()">New div</button>
          <button onclick="myFunctionRem()">Remove divs</button>
          <button onclick="myFunctionColour()">Colour change</button>
          <button onclick="myFunctionChangeText()">Div's new text</button>
        </header>
        <ul id="list">
            <li>
              <div id="innerDiv1">
                <p> My Vertical Div1 </p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div id="innerDiv2">
                <p>My Vertical Div2 </p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div id="innerDiv3">
                <p>My Vertical Div3 </p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div id="innerDiv4">
                <p>My Vertical Div4</p>
              </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It's actually allowed to create custom elements in browsers that support them but they need to be properly defined first. I doubt OP is ready for that yet though

Comment: Updated part about custom tags

Comment: Quite honestly I don't think OP even realized they were using another element's id in `createElement` rather than a tag name